# Get proper absolute rotation after mesh.lookAt

Tags: rotation, three.js, angle, euler-angles, radians

After I call `mesh2.lookAt(mesh1.position)` mesh2.rotation.y is the same value whether mesh1.position.z is positive or negative, but mesh2.rotation.x and z are either 0 or -PI -- so there actually is some information in the quaternion/matrix.

I tried to manually call update functions for every matrix and getWorldRotation.

What the heck is going on? How to get the absolute rotation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I meant "in the Euler". The quaternion seems quite fine. The Euler does not. Manually calculating `new THREE.Euler().setFromQuaternion(mesh2.quaternion.normalize())` after lookAt has the same odd result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get why yet, but setting the order of the euler (Y first) fixed it.
I'm just rotating around one axis.